# Analytics sendEvent not sending data

Tags: android, google-analytics

I've been trying several implementations for sending events using the Google Analytics library v2 but none are sending data to my Analytics dashboard.

The simplest implementation that should be working is

```
EasyTracker.getTracker().sendEvent("Social", "Opened Share App", "Clicked", (long) 1);
EasyTracker.getInstance().dispatch();
```

Other things like activities and screens get tracked just fine.

I've also tried by using:

```
mGaInstance = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
mGaTracker = mGaInstance.getTracker("UA-XXXXXX-X");
```

And then using that tracker to send events, but this doesn't send data either. I've also read about events needing over 24 hours to register. This really seems weird since everything else in analytics is basically instant, is this true though? I'm not finding any confirmation of this.

With debugging turned on in analytics.xml the following appears in logcat

```
putHit called
Sending hit to store
PowerSaveMode terminated.
Thread[GAThread,5,main]: dispatch running...
User-Agent: GoogleAnalytics/2.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.1; nl-nl; HTC One X Build/JRO03C)
Host: ssl.google-analytics.com
GET /collect?ul=nl-nl&ev=1&ht=1370875183876&sr=720x1280&a=72697680&aid=com.package.android&ea=Opened+Share+App&cid=8e7dc0b4-d03c-4ccb-8bed-f549f16a1b1d&ec=Social&av=0.1.1&v=1&t=event&el=Clicked&an=My+App&tid=UA-XXXXXX-X&_u=.C&_v=ma1b5&cd=com.package.android.ActivityAbout&qt=39&z=103 HTTP/1.1
```

So it seems to be dispatching just fine right?

Comment: I faced the same problem. I couldn't fix it but I changed the data-sending frequency and let it handle sending data, worked for my case.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Do could you post a snippet of how you handled it or maybe a link to a related sample? I'd like to try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so the answer was quite silly. I went back to fixing this around 23:45 and was still struggling to find an answer. Then the clock turned 00:07 and I refreshed... Tadaa, 73 events popped up for the previous day...

[image: Events in analytics]

So yea, if other people have the same issue. The first snippet of code in my question works just fine.

```
EasyTracker.getTracker().sendEvent("Social", "Opened Share App", "Clicked", (long) 1);
EasyTracker.getInstance().dispatch();
```

Calling the dispatch method isn't really needed, nor does it help with showing up anything earlier either. Just use the default value or you can read about it more [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/dispatch).

Comment: So does it always take a day for you to receive data?

Answer (score 6):

As I already commented, we're letting EasyTracker handle the data sending issues. It's not a fix, but a workaround.

The documentation: [EasyTracker Parameters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/parameters)

I created analytics.xml file in res/values. My analytics.xml file is like this:

```
<resources>
  <!--Replace placeholder ID with your tracking ID-->
  <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-********-*</string>
  <!--Enable automatic activity tracking-->
  <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

  <!--Enable automatic exception tracking-->
  <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

  <!--  dispatch period in seconds.
    Default value is 30 minutes, should set about 5 minutes in release mode.
  <bool name="ga_debug">true</bool>
  <integer name="ga_dispatchPeriod">3</integer>
   -->

  <integer name="ga_dispatchPeriod">300</integer>
</resources>
```

ga_dispatchPeriod value is in seconds. We're using 3 seconds for debugging and 300 seconds for release mode. Default value for ga_dispatchPeriod is 30 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for this variabele, I didn't know about it. It will come in handy whilst debugging. I found my real problem however.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Google Analytics Social Interaction API**

```
Tracker tracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(getActivity()
                    .getApplicationContext());

tracker.send(MapBuilder.createSocial("Twitter", "Tweet",
                    "https://developers.google.com/analytics").build());
```

[Google Analtyics Social Interactions - Android SDK](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/social)